# Authenticaton Postgres error while using Docker Compose, Python Django and Gitlab CI

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I use Gitlab CI to make pipeline with building Docker image with my Django app. I saved some .env variables to Gitlab variables. They are succesfully calling and working, but there is

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
```

I have checked all passwords and variables, they are correct.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:18.09.7-dind

before_script:
  - apk add py-pip python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
  - pip3 install docker-compose

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker build -t myapp:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml run --rm myapp ./manage.py test
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml run --rm myapp ./manage.py check
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml down -v
```